# Python: Add contents of a csv file to a list

Tags: python, list, csv, readfile

have a new issue with this that I could do with some help on.
Like before i am passing a csv (with comma as separator) into a list.
the first element in the list will always be an integer but the next two will be strings.
I'm trying to add a new line to the csv which will have an incremented number in the first element but I will also add hash strings in the other two elements.
It works on the first run as the file is empty but when it tries a second run I get an error

> chain_list = [int(i) for i in lineList[-1].split(',')]
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9891b18cf04418b92c0ee611201da47ef00471090aebdfa6667097d81d0832cb2edab83f65a4dc497fbffc4332d7e794'

The first line of the file that i'm passing in contains:

> 1,0,9891b18cf04418b92c0ee611201da47ef00471090aebdfa6667097d81d0832cb2edab83f65a4dc497fbffc4332d7e794

My code looks like this at the minute. Not sure how to get around this?

```py
#Check if chain_info.txt exists
CHAIN_FILE_exists = os.path.isfile(CHAIN_FILE)
#If chainfile is empty set element 0 in list to 1
if CHAIN_FILE_exists:
    if os.stat(CHAIN_FILE).st_size == 0:
        print('empty')
        fileHandle = open (CHAIN_FILE, 'a')
        fileHandle.write('1,0,0')
        fileHandle.close()
        fileHandle = open (CHAIN_FILE)
        lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
        fileHandle.close()       
        chain_list = lineList[-1].split(',')
        chain_list = [int(i) for i in lineList[-1].split(',')]
        increment_value = 1
        print('1 chain list now is: ' + str(chain_list))
    else:
        #Read the last line of a file
        fileHandle = open (CHAIN_FILE)
        lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
        fileHandle.close()
        #Take last line of file and add to a list called chain_list
        chain_list = lineList[-1].split(',')
        chain_list = [int(i) for i in lineList[-1].split(',')]
        #increment the first value in the list by 1, this will be used to determine the block number
        increment_value = (chain_list[0])
        increment_value = increment_value +1
        chain_list.remove (chain_list[0])
        chain_list.insert (0,increment_value)
        print('chain list now is: ' + str(chain_list))
        #Open file
        fileHandle = open (CHAIN_FILE, 'a')
        #Write the contents of the list to the chain file on a new line and separate with a comma
        fileHandle.write('\n' + str(chain_list[0]) + ',' + str(chain_list[1]))
        fileHandle.close()
else:    
    print ('file does not exist')
```

Comment: What is the delimiter for your `csv` file?

Comment: it's just going to be a comma

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
your_list = []
for i in lineList[-1].split(','):
    try:your_list.append(int(i))
    except:your_list.append(i)
```

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem. :-)

Comment: Just a follow up question. The file will contain numbers but when they are added to the list they seem to be strings. How can I add them to the list as integers?

Comment: Cheers, that worked but now facing another related issue. Will try and figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` module to parse the CSV content row-wise. Simply advance to the last line then, discarding intermediate data:

```
import csv

with open('c:\\securelog_workfiles\\chain_info.txt') as data:
    for row in csv.reader(data):  # parse each line to a row
        continue  # skip through the csv row-wise
    last_line_data = row
```

This works for arbitrarily large files, since it only ever loads individual lines instead of the entire file at once.

If the file is huge and you want to avoid the overhead of parsing discarded lines, advance to the last line and parse only that. You can either use `next(csv.reader([row]))` to parse the last line, or something like `row.split(...)` if the format is simple:

```
with open('c:\\securelog_workfiles\\chain_info.txt') as data:
    for row in data:  # do not parse each line
        continue  # skip through the csv row-wise
    last_line_data = row.split(',')  # parse the last line explicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help. Eventually got this little piece working. The first line of the file which is always 1,0,0 is being passed into a list called lineList as integers.
Then the first element of this list which has a value of 1 is incremented and printed to the screen.

```py
import os
import io
import sys
import zipfile
import shutil
import csv
from os import path
from zipfile import ZipFile
from shutil import make_archive

#input file
chain_file = 'c:\\securelog_workfiles\\chain_info.txt'

#Check if chain_info.txt exists
chain_file_exists = os.path.isfile(chain_file)
if chain_file_exists:
    if os.stat(chain_file).st_size == 0:
        print('empty')
        fileHandle = open (chain_file, 'a')
        fileHandle.write('1,0,0')
        fileHandle.close()
    else:
        #Read the last line of a file
        fileHandle = open (chain_file)
        lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
        fileHandle.close()
        print (lineList)
        print ("The last line is:")
        print (lineList[-1])

        #split the line into separate values using the comma as the delimeter
        chain_list = lineList[-1].split(',')

        #convert the string characters from the file into integers before adding 
        #to the list
        chain_list = [int(i) for i in lineList[-1].split(',')]
        print (chain_list)

        #increment 1 to 2
        increment_value = (chain_list[0])
        increment_value = increment_value +1

        #remove the first element from the list
        chain_list.remove (chain_list[0])
        #verifying that the 1st element was removd
        print (chain_list)

        #insert the incremented value into the list
        chain_list.insert (0,increment_value)
        print('chain list now is: ' + str(chain_list))

else:    
    print ('file does not exist')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1 = []
for ele in line:
   list1.append(ele[0])

list2 = []
for ele in line:
   list2.append(ele[0])

list3 = []
for ele in line:
   list3.append(ele[0])

your_list = []
your_list.append(list1[-1])
your_list.append(list2[-1])
your_list.append(list3[-1])
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer came up in the review queue because of length and content. Posts like this are flagged as low quality because code only answers are generally discouraged on StackOverflow. Please add an explanation to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that.. Have added more comments to the code to explain what it's supposed to do and have added more explanation to the answer.